# Replace all occurences of certain char and get all variations

Tags: java, string, replace

I have a word on which I need to replace a certain character with an asterisk, but I need to get all the replaced variations from this word. For eg. I want to replace character 'e' with an asterisk in:

```
String word = telephone;
```

but to get this list as a result:

```
List of words = [t*lephone, tel*phone, telephon*, t*l*phone, t*lephon*, tel*phon*, t*l*phon*];
```

Is there a quick way to do this in Java?

Comment: I don't think so. I suggest doing a simple recursive algorithm (DFS).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will do that in a recursive way:

```
public static Set<String> getPermutations(final String string, final char c) {
    final Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();
    final int indexofChar = string.indexOf(c);
    if (indexofChar <= 0) {
        permutations.add(string);
    } else {
        final String firstPart = string.substring(0, indexofChar + 1);
        final String firstPartReplaced = firstPart.replace(c, '*');
        final String lastPart = string.substring(indexofChar + 1, string.length());
        for (final String lastPartPerm : getPermutations(lastPart, c)) {
            permutations.add(firstPart + lastPartPerm);
            permutations.add(firstPartReplaced + lastPartPerm);
        }
    }
    return permutations;
}
```

It adds the original `String` to the output, so:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String word = "telephone";
    System.out.println(getPermutations(word, 'e'));
}
```

Outputs:

```
[telephone, t*lephone, tel*phone, t*l*phone, telephon*, t*lephon*, tel*phon*, t*l*phon*]
```

But you can always call `remove` on the returned `Set` with the original word.